# Side margins right and left are not equal

Tags: margins, fontspec, babel, polyglossia, octavo

Please look at my MWE. I would expect odd and even side margins being the same but they are not. What I am doing that is wrong?
(I added most of my preamble just in case it matters...).

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
layoutsize={110mm, 190mm},
textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
outer=1.5cm,
inner=1cm,
top=1.5cm,
bottom=2cm
    ]
    {geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{layout}
%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%STARTHERE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\layout

\chapter{1}
\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You define two margins of unequal length. The outer margin is the right one and the inner one is the left side. If you want equal margins, you need to keep those the same (or insert a bindingoffset of 5 mm which will equal both sides too) See the manual of `geometry`  about the definitions of inner and outer.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I do not understand. In the geometry manual it says "There are four margins: left, right, top and bottom. For twosided documents, horizontal margins should be called inner and outer." So I though by setting inner = 1 cm it means that the inner margin of odd and even pages should be the same... Please can you clarify what I should put in my argument to obtain this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `twoside` to the list of arguments with which the `geometry` package is loaded?

Comment: Tried but no changes

Comment: Are you creating a book and would you want to bind the book using a binder? Or do you write a report or article that doesn’t require binding?

Comment: In a book you have an outer margin that is slightly larger than the inner margin. On odd pages the outer margin is the right margin as the odd pages will be on the right side of an open book. The inner margin is then the left one. On even pages both margins are reversed. The outer one is then the left margin on the left side of the book. The bindingoffset is used to have room for a binder and is actually added to the inner margin (as that will be the place where the binder holes will be)

Comment: It is a book that will be published. It is a series and I'm volume 236 so I cannot change the typography at this point :-). The publisher gave me this measures: Textwidth cm 8,5; Outer margin: cm 1,5; Inner margin: cm 1; Top: cm 1,7; Bottom: cm 2,2

Comment: What would be the right options to geometry to obtain the measures above? (I think the binding offset is already calculated in the 1 cm inner margins as looking at the actual other books in the collection the actual visible margin is a couple of mm less)

Comment: Have you checked whether the `paperwidth=115mm`, `paperheight=195mm`, and
`layoutsize={110mm, 190mm}` are mutually compatible? For sure, if I comment out `layoutsize={110mm, 190mm}`, I instantly get better results.

Comment: Well .. if the publisher provided you with those margins, then they should be unequal. The page is printed towards the inside of the book, having larger outside margins to the right on odd pages and to the left on even pages.

Comment: Yes MICO your suggestion works!

Comment: If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mico would you like to post an answer? I'm editing the question now to add the `octavo` tag that I created so it will be bumped to the top now anyhow :)

Comment: @JamesT - Thanks for the suggestion, will do. (Truth be told, I hadn't noticed the two comments by the OP, dated March 7, until just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you comment out the option

```
layoutsize={110mm, 190mm}
```

while loading the `geometry` package. It doesn't seem to do anything useful anyway, at least not in the test document at hand.

A separate comment: Don't load both `babel` and `polyglossia`. Use one or the other, *but not both simultaneously*.

[image]

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt, italian]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
    %%%layoutsize={110mm, 190mm}, % <-- comment out this line
    textwidth=85mm, textheight=155mm, 
    outer=1.5cm, inner=1cm, 
    top=1.5cm,   bottom=2cm,
    showframe
    ]
    {geometry}
\usepackage{varioref,babel,microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol} % do you need this?
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

%%\usepackage{polyglossia} % don't load both 'babel' and 'polyglossia'
%%\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

\begin{document}
%% \sloppy % <-- why?

%\layout

\chapter{AA}
\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```